# python cannot listen for UDP and send UDP at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, udp

I've been trying to make a small server with python. I want to be able to constantly listen for packets incoming but also send my own back to clients. However this doesn't work as using `input(str)` awaits an answer and an infinite `while` loop does the same. I tried to make a new thread for one of them to listen on but
`ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` is called every time I send a packet. here is my code:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, port, ip):
        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip
        self.server = None

    def listen(self):
        print("listening...")

        data, address = self.server.recvfrom(self.port)
        print("recieved: " + data.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
        self.listen()

    def start(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
        self.server.bind(('', 9999))
        th = Thread(target=self.listen)
        th.start()
        self.awaitCommands()

    def awaitCommands(self):
        try:
            self.send(input("=> "))
            self.awaitCommands()
        except:
            print("ERROR: cannot send the command!")

    def send(self, byte_message):
        self.server.sendto(byte_message.encode('utf-8'), (self.ip, self.port))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("IP found on machine: " + getIP())
    server = Server(10000, getIP())

    server.start()
```

This starts the server and listens, and prints `=>`, waiting for a command. When I enter a command and press enter the error occurs. Is there any way I can constantly listen for incoming packets but at the same time send my own? I might be doing this horribly wrong idk.

Comment: btw your `awaitCommands()` and `listen()` methods call themselves so you may run out of stack space when you get your program working.

Comment: What is the meaning of `self.port`? It is used as an UDP port in `sendto()` but also as a buffer capacity in `recvfrom()`. Are you sure a process is listening to UDP on `(self.ip, self.port)`?

Comment: yes a process is listening and it worked fine, i can send info over. self .port is defined in the init method and it works fine.

Comment: my `awaitCommands()` and `listen()` both had `while True` loops but i was just changing them to figure out the problem, either way they both produce the same problem